# How to find an ancestor element and query its metadata

Tags: javascript, jquery, parents

I have an html which contains nested tables:

```
<table ....
<tbody ...
<tr ...
    <td class="Field">item1_1</td>
        <td class="Value">
        <table ...
        <tbody...
        <tr
            <td class="Field">0</td>
            <td class="Value">
            <table ...
                ....
```

The clickable element are the Fields. When the user clicks a field, I need to find the table which contains its table (2 tables up) and check its metadata.
I tried to use:

```
field.parents("table")[1]
```

This returns the right table but it doesn't allow me to query its metadata:

```
field.parents("table")[1].data("isArray")
```

Can you please help me figure out how to query the metadata of the containing table?

Thanks,
Li

p.s. 
I've only managed to do it by using:

```
field.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().data("isArray")
```

but I really want to avoid such ugliness.

Comment: hate to ask but have you considered using something like jQuery or Zepto to help you out on this?

Comment: You appear to be using jquery, though you have not tagged the question as such.  If you are using jquery and would like answers related to jquery, please modify your tags.

Comment: @tkone `.parent()`, `.parents()` and `.data()` are jQuery methods. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that array indexing the jquery object will return a dom object.  You can instead use `eq` to get you a jquery object.

```
field.parents("table").eq(1).data("isArray")
```

If you are able to modify the html.  An even cleaner approach would be to assign a class to the table you are trying to get and then use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
field.closest(".someClass").data("isArray")
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing this call

`field.parents("table")[1].data("isArray")`

I'm supposing that you're using jQuery.data() method.
If yes, then the call by index will return you an HTMLElement and not jQuery object.
In this case change your code to

`$(field.parents("table")[1]).data("isArray")`

Answer (score 1):

`eq()` will solve the problem but for the sake of simplicity, you could assign an `id` to the outer table and create a reference to the `table` just once, without the need to find it at every user click.

Also consider that `eq()` usage could create some mantainance problem if you nest again your fields in another table/s, because you're completely relying on the index of the collection returned by `parents()` to retrieve the outermost table

otherwise, if that table is the only one with a inline `data-*` attribute you could find it with

```
field.closest('table[data-isArray]');
```

Comment: I had assume this was to be used in multiple separate tables (not sure why). If this is a single static table then this is definitely the best approach.